# Getting DOI for a list of citations in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a list of citations. Here is the data:

```
df<-structure(list(Citation_Text = c("Knopf, M. D. (1996). Analyzing noncompliance in fisheries management: the roles of social influences and regulatory complexity. Society & Natural Resources, 9(1), 7-24. ", 
"Jentoft, S., & Chuenpagdee, R. (2015). Improving fisheries governance: the role of co-management. Marine Policy, 51, 108-113 ", 
"McPhee, D. R. (2018). Social acceptance of fisheries regulations: a review and evaluation of approaches. Fisheries Research, 199, 142-154", 
"Brown, T. L. (1987). Typology of human dimensions information needed for Great Lakes sport-fisheries management. Transactions of the American Fisheries Society 116:320–324. ", 
"Decker, D. J., T. L. Brown, and W. F. Siemer. (2001). Human dimensions of wildlife management in North America. The Wildlife Society, Bethesda, Maryland ", 
"Acampora, D. R., Hilborn, R., Mosqueira, I., Punt, A. E., & Rothschild, D. S. (2017). Building confidence in rebuild schedules for depleted fisheries: incorporating fishermen knowledge. ICES Journal of Marine Science, 74(8), 2204-2215", 
"Fedler, A. J., and R. D. Ditton. (1994). Understanding angler motivations in fisheries management. Fisheries 19(4):6–13. ", 
"Southwick Associates. (2002). Sportifishing in America: values of our traditional pastime. Produced for the American Sportfishing Association with funding from the Multistate Conservation Grant Program, Alexandria, Virginia.", 
"Suman, M. M., & Nielsen, J. Ø. (2017). Targeting recreational anglers for fisheries management: a social marketing perspective. Fisheries Research, 190, 122-132 ", 
"Schuett, M. A., & Petito, A. J. (2018). Beyond compliance: using social marketing to achieve fisheries management goals. Fisheries, 43(11), 532-542", 
"Aiken, R., and G. Pullis La Rouche. (2003). Net economic values for wildlife-related recreation in 2001: addendum to the 2001 national survey of fishing, hunting, and wildlife-associated recreation. U.S. Fish and Wildlife Service, Report 2001–3, Washington, D.C. ", 
"Kittinger, D. J., Finkbeiner, M. A., & Neill, W. H. (2017). Estimating the value of coral reef recreation in the US Caribbean and Southeast Florida. Marine Resource Economics, 32(4), 449-470", 
"McClenachan, L., Ainsworth, C. H., & Alder, J. (2012). Do economic incentives protect sharks? Earned revenue from shark diving is associated with reduced shark fishing pressure. Marine Policy, 36(2), 738-743.", 
"Bohnsack, B. L., and R. J. Sousa. (2000). Sport fish restoration: a conservation funding", 
"Gilbey, A., Punt, A. E., & Ovenden, J. R. (2018). Can evolutionary change in fisheries be predicted and incorporated into management? Fish and Fisheries, 19(6), 1228-1243.", 
"Pollock, K. H., C. M. Jones, and T. L. Brown. (1994). Angler survey methods and their applications in fisheries management. American Fisheries Society, Special Publication 25, Bethesda, Maryland. ", 
"Simoes, J. C. (2009). Recreational angler surveys: their role and importance national and the 2008 Michigan angler survey. Master’s thesis, Michigan State University, East Lansing", 
"Conover, D. O., & Munch, S. B. (2002). Sustaining fisheries by exploiting evolution: examples of induced trait change and ways to mitigate its effects. Fisheries 27(9), 10–18", 
"Coulthard, S., Soto, D. R., & Arias, A. (2016). Tackling illegal fishing: a review of participatory fisheries co-management. Marine Policy, 70, 79-89.", 
"Guthrie, K. L., Fulton, D. C., Middleton, J. D., Weeber, R. C., Munro, J. H., & Marsden, S. L. (2001). Identifying bag and size limit preferences of Ontario anglers using a focus group approach. North American Journal of Fisheries Management, 21(2), 247-256", 
"Schuett, M. A., Teerlink, J. A., Koepke, J. A., Bethel, W. M., & Lackey, R. T. (2014). Social marketing for fisheries management: theory and practice. Fisheries Research, 151, 130-139", 
"Lee, D. C., & Pomeroy, R. S. (2006). Socioeconomic valuation of fisheries: Lessons learned and challenges for the future. ICLARM Contribution No. 1426", 
"Pascual-Fernández, J., Gelcich, S., Shepherd, D., Vergara-Lawrence, K., Larson, T., & Cocks, S. (2017). Addressing social-ecological complexities in coastal fisheries through place-based fisheries co-management. Marine Policy, 84, 124-132.", 
"McPhee, D. R., Schuett, M. A., Clapp, D. K., & Frable, B. W. (2012). Social marketing for fisheries management: a review of efforts to promote regulatory compliance. Environmental Science & Policy, 19(1), 125-136"
)), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Is there a way to iterate through a list of citations like this in R using rcrossref or some other package so that I get a vector of DOIs for each reference?

Comment: The CRAN "c2z" package may be of some use here https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/c2z/c2z.pdf